# Extending a class with multiple classes

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

I'm creating a class that extends another class.

```
public class ASClass extends UIComponent{

}
```

but I'm trying to make it extend multiple classes. Is this somehow possible? I read it may be possible through composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but only through a slightly hacky method of using the #include pragma. Here is a Darron Schall article explaining how: http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/10/multiple-inheritance-in-actionscript-3.cfm.

Comment: Is this similar to `compositions` or how is it different from it

Comment: @cooper: this is similar to copy and paste

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance); which is not supported in ActionScript [or as far as I knew, most modern languages w/ OO Features].  You may think you want the feature, but multiple inheritance opens up a huge can of worms.

I suggest you look into [interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computer_science%29) as they are the intended alternative to multiple inheritance.  Here is some [Adobe Documentation on Interfaces](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=projects_035_29.html).  Interfaces do not allow you to share an implementation, though.

You can use ActionScript includes as one way to share implementation between multiple files.